# Connect two VLANs on an NE1032 Lenovo L3 Switch

Tags: switch, vlan, layer3

I just got a new Lenovo ThinkSwitch NE1032 with some 1G sfp. I have already created two VLANs called FE and BE that have the following IDs: 2,3. I have managed to assign an IP subnet to both of them, 10.10.10.X/24 for the VLAN 1 and 10.10.11.X/24 for VLAN 2 and I was looking to connect them through a gateway.
Does anyone know how to create a gateway and connect two VLANs on that kind of switch ?

Thanks

Comment: The gateway for each VLAN is the IP address on the VLAN interface.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I will try it out later!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are very capable Layer 3 switches (ie, they contain a router in the same box) and have an 800-page manual which really it's wise to at least skim.

This should get you going, however ...

You enable routing with

```
ip route
```

You create virtual interfaces in the two VLANs with whatever addressing you choose:

```
interface vlan 2
  ip address 10.10.10.1 /24

interface vlan 3
  ip address 10.10.11.1 /24
```

You won't need to add any routes because you'll have interface routes between those two VLANs.

Comment: HI, thank you for your clear explanation of VLANs, i will try to redo my VLANs using your commands.

Comment: If any answer helps, please mark it as "accepted"